# Angular material table - using two paginators, one for columns and one for rows

Tags: angular, angular-material

I see that material has a table component. https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

That table component has a paginator so you dont have to load all the rows at once.

I am looking for something where I can also use a paginator on the columns as well.

If I have a data set of 100 rows by 100 columns, I only want to show a 10 column by 10 row table and have a paginator let the user traverse over the table.

Does anyone know of something that can do this?

Comment: That sounds like a really bad UX/UI decision.

Comment: @Mihailo If you have a really big table with lots of columns and lots of rows how else would you handle it?

Comment: If you really need to have a lot of columns the best you could to is wrap the table in a container div with `overflow-x: scroll` and the user can scroll left-right, and the pagination to traverse from page to page explicitly.

Comment: @Mihailo If there is literally hundreds of columns, I dont know if that is really the best idea. Even assuming I got some Ajax call to dynamically load sections of the table as they scroll through it, if they scrolled all the way to the end of the table and then wanted to come back to the first few columns they would spend forever scrolling back. You even suggesting using pagination for the rows. But if there could be just as many rows as there are columns, why would pagination not be a good solution for columns as well?

Comment: a table with "hundreds of columns"? I feel you bro.

Comment: @PaulMel the user wants to be able to view a table with each column representing a day and each row representing a customer. Each cell would have that customers sales for that day. And the customer wants to be able to view the data with as many days and customers selected as they want. So 100 customers over the span of even just a quarter year is 100 by 100